# Is there only one convention to define the electromagnetic field tensor?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, conventions

I know that the electromagnetic field tensor depends on which metric is used. For example wikipedia uses the $(+---)$ sign convention, but in the Griffiths we have the $(-+++)$ sign convention.

That's why on wikipedia, to define $F_{\mu \nu}$ independently of the metric tensor, they define $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu.$

However, in my electrodynamic course we define $F_{\mu\nu} = - \partial_\mu A_\nu + \partial_\nu A_\mu$ so all the signs are flipped. For example using the $(-+++)$ sign convention (and $c=1$) we get:

$F_{\mu\nu}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & E_x & E_y & E_z \\
 -E_x & 0 & -B_z & B_y \\
 -E_y & B_z & 0 & -B_x \\
 -E_z & -B_y & B_x & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

This matrix is the same as on wikipedia, and the opposite as the one in the Griffiths (all the signs flipped).

I haven't seen anyone else use the definition $F_{\mu\nu} = - \partial_\mu A_\nu + \partial_\nu A_\mu$ for the electromagnetic field tensor, so I am wondering if there is something wrong in my course, or if there is no problem by defining the tensor in this way.

Comment: In some older textbooks, the semicolon ; was used to denote the covariant derivative operation so that your course's definition would appear as $F_{\mu \nu}=A_{\mu;\nu}-A_{\nu;\mu}$. This convention, together with the chosen signature-convention, must be accounted for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you keep track of that sign in your formulas, there is no issue. All formulas in which the field tensor appears will simply have a sign difference. The fact most references use the same convention is probably the same we write [$2\pi$ instead of $\tau$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(angle)#Tau_proposals): someone choose that convention a lot of time ago and it would get messy if we used different conventions.

Comment: Hopefully those who write $(+---)$ will also eventually perceive the convenience of a single convention and accept to use the superior choice $(-+++)$.

Comment: The $A_\mu$ are also differnt in the two metrics.  If I remember correctly, it  is $A^\mu=(\phi, {\bf A})$ where ${\bf E}= -\nabla \phi- \dot {\bf A}$,  and the $A_\mu=g_{\mu\nu} A^\nu$.